# How to change the Text fontWeight (Style) throughout react-native application. (Android Bold Text Accessibilty issue)

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, user-interface

I have a project which is completed, and we are finding issue that if a Text component used from react-native haven't been given a style property fontWeight, then android accessibility setting (bold text) would change the font weight of the text. The app already have settings for preventing font scaling but bold text accessibilty does not gets overwritten.

I tried the following solutions.

```
Text.defaultProps = { ...(Text.defaultProps || {}), allowFontScaling: false }
TextInput.defaultProps = { ...(TextInput.defaultProps || {}), allowFontScaling: false }
Text.defaultProps.style = [{ fontWeight: 'normal' }] // or any other font weight 100 - 900

//or even
Text.defaultProps.style = { fontWeight: 'normal' } // so to avoid any syntex technicality is not missed. tried all.
```

The above is in the index.js of the app.

The allowFontScaling for defaultProps works but not the style part.

I have also tried some suggestions from chatGPT which simply have no effects.

`Text.defaultProps = { ...(Text.defaultProps || {}), allowFontScaling: false, importantForAccessibility:'yes' }`

and also tried adding some code in MainApplication.java, (I do no have an idea how native android code works). Which just gave error setDefaultTypeface is not a method in TextView, so i went and checked on android documentation what methods i can use, [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) which did showed that there is no method for setDefaultTypeface.

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.TextView;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Set the default font weight for TextView components
    TextView.setDefaultTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
}
```

Please help if there is a solution to deal with bold text because i cannot use a custom Text component (or even custom native module) as app is already completed.